# Trying to divide 1 million for all the cells in a row using paste special (divide), but excels says cannot change part of an array

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a row of numbers in excel, these cells have formulas that grab values from other sheet. For example, the first cell would be `=sum(offset(indirect("sheet1!E"&$c27&":F"&$c27),0,I$6-$H$6))`

Second cell in the row would be similar. I want to divide the values in this row by 1 million. So I put 1 million in another cell, and copy it, select the entire row, paste special, operation = divide. A window pops up saying I cannot change a part of array. I understand that there is an array in my original formula, but I am just dividing that number by another million. Why am I not able to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Why not use INDEX instead of OFFSET/INDIRECT also, if you want to divide the outcome why not add that to the formula `=[your formula]/1000

Comment: Because the file is done by other people and there are like 200 rows in the sheet. I am adjusting the values to divide by 1 million. But we still want the previous formula to be in there, so trying to figure out a way to do this faster. Thanks

Comment: Index is faster, since it's not volatile. OFFSET and INDIRECT are both volatile and cause each cell containing the formula to recalculate at **any** change within the document.

Comment: `=SUM(INDEX(Sheet1!$1:$1048576,$C27,(I$6-$H$6)+{5,6}))/1000`

Comment: For you to be getting that message must mean that the formulas in question have actually been committed with `CSE`, i.e. have curly brackets around them. This is the only reason your Paste Special operation is failing. However, the formula you posted does not actually require committing with `CSE`, even in legacy versions of Excel. Converting it to a `non-CSE` formula will allow you to carry out the desired Paste Special operation. That said, it really is quite a bad formula indeed. If you can, I strongly suggest changing to an `INDEX` equivalent, as suggested, for example, by P.b..

Comment: Thank you all for helping!